# Use an actionlistener on combobox

Tags: java, combobox

I want to populate my combobox with data when I click an item in my combobox. So if I click 2IAO3A I want to see 2 names, Luca en Wessel. When I click on 2IAO3B I want to see the other 2 names. I don't get only 2 names, whenever I click it just adds all of it into the second combobox.[image]

```
package oop;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class mainclass extends JPanel {



public mainclass()  {

    String[] klassen = new String[] {"2IAO3A", "2IAO3B"};
    String[] leerlingen = new String[] {};
    JButton klik = new JButton("Klik");
    JComboBox<String> klaslijst = new JComboBox<String>(klassen);
    JComboBox<String> leerlinglijst = new JComboBox<String>(leerlingen);

    add(klaslijst);
    add(leerlinglijst);
    add(klik);

    klik.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

              String klas = (String)klaslijst.getSelectedItem();

              if(klas == "2IAO3A") 
                 {
                     leerlinglijst.addItem("Luca");
                     leerlinglijst.addItem("Wessel");

                 }
               if (klas == "2IAO3B") 
               {
                      leerlinglijst.addItem("Berend");
                      leerlinglijst.addItem("Cas");

                }

          }
    }
         );

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are getting the 4 names at all the time or just on your second selection. If you are getting all the names from and after your second selections, you can do the following changes,

```
if(klas == "2IAO3A") 
{
leerlinglijst.removeAllElements();
leerlinglijst.addItem("Luca");
leerlinglijst.addItem("Wessel");
}
if (klas == "2IAO3B") 
{
leerlinglijst.removeAllElements();
leerlinglijst.addItem("Berend");
leerlinglijst.addItem("Cas");
}
```

see if this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

For understandment: you want to populate the second combo box when you select an item in the first one, or when you click the button?

If you want to respond to changes in the first combo box then you need an ItemListener to listen to item state change of the combo box!!

But if it is the button then: try to clear the combo box before you add other items.

```
leerlinglijst.removeAllItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use a Map instead of the different arrays. This will make it easier if you want to add more klassen en leerlingen.

```
    Map<String, String[]> klasLijst = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    klasLijst.put(klassen[0], new String[] {"Jan", "Piet"});
    klasLijst.put(klassen[1], new String[] {"Gert", "Samson"});

    String selected = klaslijst.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String[] namenLijst = klasLijst.get(selected);
    if(namenLijst != null){
        // add namenLijst           
    } else {
        // add empty array
    }
```